# Cosa significa "a torciglione" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *La nascita del giullare* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> –
>    Ma io non so, non so dire parole rovesciate... non so 
>   fare il controcanto da buffone... e nemanco filastrocche **a 
>   torciglione** beffardo che la lingua mi si inceppa dentro i denti… col cervello che tengo ubriacato dal sole e dalla 
>   fatica!

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "a torciglione" in questo passaggio. 
Ho cercato il vocabolo "torciglione" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Questa espressione appare un po' più avanti nel testo:

> E cosí mi ha preso la testa, ha portato le labbra sue dolci alle mie e mi ha baciato. Mi è arrivato un gran tremore di fuoco sulle labbra... la lingua ha cominciato a trillare **a torciglione** come una biscia. Parole nuove scivolavano rotolando nel mio cervello. Ogni pensiero mi si rivoltava... ogni idea mi sortiva capovolta.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "a torciglione" in questo contesto?

Comment: Se non vado errato, torciglione indica una cosa intrecciata o ritorta; nel primo caso la filastrocca _a torciglione_ indica che era complicata da pronunciare (in italiano vedi anche alla voce: _scioglilingua_ ). Nella seconda espressione il significato sembra analogo, anche se serve un po' più contesto... mi pare di capire che l'emozione del bacio abbia "attorcigliato" i suoi pensieri e le sue capacità di comunicazione ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torciglione (o [tortiglione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tortiglione/)) indica una forma a spirale:

> Oggetto, elemento attorto a spirale (vi concorre, in varî sign. e usi,
>   la forma torciglione).

Nel contesto da te indicato il significato è, nel primo caso, che la filastrocca era talmente veloce da fargli attorcigliare la lingua e, nel secondo caso, in maniera simile la lingua si contorceva quasi fosse un rettile.